# Canon XF105 streaming

Tags: streaming

Can the Canon XF105 be used for streaming to Facebook Live and record the service simultaneously?  We are trying to utilize an existing Canon XF105 to stream to Facebook Live during our services while connecting sound to a digital sound mixer.  Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information here about what you are trying to do.  There doesn't appear to be any way to directly stream to Facebook Live using the XF105.  It is also not clear how the sound mixer is being used.  What hardware are you using for the stream?  What kind of mixer do you have?  What are you trying to accomplish overall?  Does the recording need to have the audio from the mixer?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the capabilities of the XF105, there is no reason you could not simultaneously record to memory card and use the SDI or HDMI output of the camera.  It appears that you can get clean outputs on those feeds to avoid menus and such being present on the output.

The XF105 can't directly stream however, so you will need some type of device to create the stream.  You can either use a computer with a capture card or use a dedicated stream encoder that generates the stream directly.

For audio, if you have the ability to send an aux output from the mixing console, I would suggest using the XLR inputs on the XF105 in line mode to take a direct audio output feed from the sound board itself.  This way both your recording and the stream will have direct audio from the console.  If possible, doing a custom mix on an aux output is slightly preferable since ideal levels will vary slightly between the room vs a direct recording, but using room levels will produce sufficiently high quality results if you don't have the manpower to do both mixes simultaneously.